# Remove windows 2000 from the guest version list in vSphere client

Tags: vmware, vsphere

We have a customer that has a weird requirement to remove/hide Windows 2000 
from the list of guest versions in vSphere client (as highlighted in the attached image). I guess this is not something vSphere officially support, just wondering if it is possible by modifying some config file or the backend database, please advice. Thanks very much.
[image: vSphere client with version list]

Comment: is this a question for serverfault?

Comment: Please help move it if it makes sense.thx.